# Is there any way to ensure that few symbols of static library get definitely loaded into .so file?

Tags: gcc, c++, g++, ld

We have a huge amount of cpp files and taking a piece of code where we need some clarification regarding that. As we have cpp files we compile those into multiple static libraries and those result into one shared library.

Considering two cpp files those belong to different libraries.

a.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void ExternFunction ();
void PrintFromLib1 ()
{
        printf ("I am from Lib1");
}
```

b.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Lib1.h" // header file of a.cpp 

void ExternFunction ()
{
   printf ("ExternFunction");
}

void PrintFromLib2 ()
{
        printf ("I am from Lib2");
}
```

Inside .a files I am able to see all the functions inside here but when we create .so file none of the symbols are being loaded there.

But, if I pass a cpp file where these functions get invoked then the symbols are being loaded into .so file.

Even the extern function doesn't come into symbol unless we reference it.

[image]

`Compilation steps:`

1. g++ -c -o Lib1.o Lib1.cpp -fPIC
2. g++ -c -o Lib2.o Lib2.cpp -fPIC
3. ar rcs Lib1.a Lib1.o
4. ar rcs Lib2.a Lib2.o
5. gcc -shared -o Result.so Lib1.a Lib2.a

Is my understanding correct that unless we reference it doesn't get loaded?

So, is there any way to ensure that these symbols get added definitely into the .so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try gcc -o Result.so -fwhole-file Lib1.a Lib2.a -fno-whole-file

Comment: Read `man strip`. `strip` offers several symbol deletion choices.